# How long does Symphytum orientale, white comfrey, live?

Tags: perennials

How long does  Symphytum orientale, white comfrey, live?

Answer (score 3):

Forever.

Ok, maybe not so long, but from root/rhizome/bulbs/tuber it generates new clones, so it should continue live in the same place, if the same condition remain.

Comment: Is there an easy way to create a new plant at a different location by cutting a bit of stem or root?

Comment: @JohnNygate: you should ask it as new question. I'm more on wild flower habits, and not about how to cultivate them. But sure other will tell you how to do it.